# How to persist IsolatedStorageSettings after terminate the application

Tags: windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage, exit-code

How to retain the saved isolatedstoragesettings while at application launch

I used exception for termination on backevents :

```
     protected void _BackKeyPress(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("Do you want to close the application?", "Q", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel) != MessageBoxResult.OK)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Add("key2", "33r4 ");
        }
        else
        {
           if (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("Key"))
        {
            IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["Key"] = App.Current.ViewModel;
        }
        else
        {
            IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Add("Key", App.Current.ViewModel);
        }
           throw new Exception("ExitApplication");
        }
    }
```

I try to save the viewmodel which declares in app.xaml.cs, but cant able to get the isolatedstorage settings value in it, at launch. But It compiles and run successfully.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the [`IsolatedStorageSettings.Save`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragesettings.save%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) method:

```
protected void _BackKeyPress(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (MessageBox.Show("Do you want to close the application?", "Q", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel) != MessageBoxResult.OK)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Add("key2", "33r4 ");
        IsolatedStorageSettings.Save();
    }
    else
    {
        if (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("Key"))
        {
            IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["Key"] = App.Current.ViewModel;
        }
        else
        {
            IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Add("Key", App.Current.ViewModel);
        }
        IsolatedStorageSettings.Save();
        throw new Exception("ExitApplication");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I used already in else part, when we press "ok" to close the application.

Comment: THe problem is that you need to call it after setting the new values. In your case, that's just before exiting via the throw new Exception. Your should try with my code, I think it will work.